# Accordion script not working

Tags: jquery, html

How do I get an accordion dropdown for `<td class="name">@item["name"]</td>`. The accordion script below is not recognized in the code.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Table:

```
<table class="diag" style="background: url('.png');border:none">
     <tbody>
          @foreach (var item in Model.project)
          {                            
               @:<tr>
                 <td class="image">
                     <img src="@item["image"]" />
                 </td>
                 <td class="name">@item["name"]</td>

                 <td id="accordion">
                    <ul>
                       <li>Option 1</li>
                       <li>Option 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>

              @:</tr>
           }
```

Comment: You have no element called #accordion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to insert one div or some element with id="accordion".

Jquery # selector search for an element with id == accordion.

So you should have:

```
<td class="name" id="{@item['name']}">
   @item["name"]
</td>
```

In addition, you should make sure to call accordion function after the table has been created